# White Spacing around navigation bar (mobile only)

Tags: html, css, navbar

White spacing appears at the sides of the mobile navbar. This is caused by a custom css sheet (below) I created because initially the logo did not centre correctly on some browser types.

I believe this may be due to the initial line of css code, but removing displaces the menu.

I want to remove the white gaps for mobile viewing, without affecting the desktop menu view at all.

```css
/* custom css for sunplay */


header.main-header .mainbar-container .mainbar {
    display: flex;
}

header.main-header .mainbar-container .mainbar .mainbar-row {
 display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center !important;
    margin: 0;
}

header.main-header .mainbar-container .mainbar .col-auto {
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

header.main-header .mainbar-container .mainbar .col-auto .navbar-header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.lqd-css-sticky-wrap .ld-parallax-wrap.parallax-applied span.split-inner, .ld-parallax-wrap.parallax-applied span.split-inner {
    transform: translateY(0px) !important;
}


@media(max-width: 480px){
.ld-parallax-wrap .lqd-lines.split-unit .split-inner{
 font-size: 53px !important;
    letter-spacing: 0;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#3ed2a7">

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.png" />

        <title>Sun play</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/yza0jhh.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/vendors/liquid-icon/liquid-icon.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/vendors/font-awesome/css/fontawesome.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/vendors/font-awesome/css/brands.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/vendors/font-awesome/css/solid.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/css/theme-vendors.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/css/theme.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/css/themes/restaurant.css" />
       
        <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
        <!-- Head Libs -->


    </head>
    <body data-mobile-nav-trigger-alignment="right" data-mobile-nav-align="left" data-mobile-nav-style="classic" data-mobile-nav-shceme="gray" data-mobile-header-scheme="gray" data-mobile-nav-breakpoint="1199">

        <div id="wrap">

            <header class="main-header main-header-overlay">

                <div class="mainbar-wrap">
                    <div class="megamenu-hover-bg"></div><!-- /.megamenu-hover-bg -->
                    <div class="container mainbar-container">
                        <div class="mainbar">
                            <div class="row mainbar-row align-items-lg-stretch">



                                <div class="col-auto">

                                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-header-collapse">

                                        <ul id="primary-nav" class="main-nav nav main-nav-hover-fade-inactive align-items-lg-stretch justify-content-lg-start" data-submenu-options='{ "toggleType":"fade", "handler":"mouse-in-out" }'>

                                            <li>
                                                <a href="index.html">
                                                    <span class="link-icon"></span>
                                                    <span class="link-txt">
                                                        <span class="link-ext"></span>
                                                        <span class="txt">
                                                            Home
                                                            <span class="submenu-expander">
                                                                <i class="fab fa-angle-down"></i>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>

                                            <li>
                                                <a href="about.html">
                                                    <span class="link-icon"></span>
                                                    <span class="link-txt">
                                                        <span class="link-ext"></span>
                                                        <span class="txt">
                                                            About Us
                                                            <span class="submenu-expander">
                                                                <i class="fab fa-angle-down"></i>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>

                                            <li class="menu-item-has-children">
                                                <a href="#">
                                                    <span class="link-icon"></span>
                                                    <span class="link-txt">
                                                        <span class="link-ext"></span>
                                                        <span class="txt">
                                                            Services
                                                            <span class="submenu-expander">
                                                                <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </a>
                                                <ul class="nav-item-children">
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="property.html">
                                                            <span class="link-icon"></span>
                                                            <span class="link-txt">
                                                                <span class="link-ext"></span>
                                                                <span class="txt">
                                                                    Property Management
                                                                    <span class="submenu-expander">
                                                                        <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </span>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="leasing.html">
                                                            <span class="link-icon"></span>
                                                            <span class="link-txt">
                                                                <span class="link-ext"></span>
                                                                <span class="txt">
                                                                    Leasing
                                                                    <span class="submenu-expander">
                                                                        <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </span>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="leasing2.html">
                                                            <span class="link-icon"></span>
                                                            <span class="link-txt">
                                                                <span class="link-ext"></span>
                                                                <span class="txt">
                                                                    Resale
                                                                    <span class="submenu-expander">
                                                                        <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </span>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="concierge.html">
                                                            <span class="link-icon"></span>
                                                            <span class="link-txt">
                                                                <span class="link-ext"></span>
                                                                <span class="txt">
                                                                    Concierge
                                                                    <span class="submenu-expander">
                                                                        <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </span>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </li>


                                                </ul>
                                            </li>




                                        </ul><!-- /#primary-nav  -->

                                    </div><!-- /#main-header-collapse -->

                                    <div class="navbar-header">
                                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" rel="home">
                                            <span class="navbar-brand-inner">
                                                <img class="mobile-logo-default" src="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/demo/preview/Sunplay_Homepage_Menu_03.png" srcset="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/demo/preview/Sunplay_Homepage_Menu_03.png 1x" alt="Ave HTML Template">
                                                <img class="logo-default" src="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/demo/preview/Sunplay_Homepage_Menu_03.png" srcset="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/demo/preview/Sunplay_Homepage_Menu_03.png 1x" alt="Ave HTML Template">
                                            </span>
                                        </a>
                                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed nav-trigger style-mobile" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-header-collapse" aria-expanded="false" data-changeclassnames='{ "html": "mobile-nav-activated overflow-hidden" }'>
                                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                            <span class="bars">
                                                <span class="bar"></span>
                                                <span class="bar"></span>
                                                <span class="bar"></span>
                                            </span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div><!-- /.navbar-header -->

                                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-header-collapse">

                                        <ul id="primary-nav" class="main-nav nav main-nav-hover-fade-inactive align-items-lg-stretch justify-content-lg-start" data-submenu-options='{ "toggleType":"fade", "handler":"mouse-in-out" }'>

                                            <li>
                                                <a href="restaurant.html">
                                                    <span class="link-icon"></span>
                                                    <span class="link-txt">
                                                        <span class="link-ext"></span>
                                                        <span class="txt">
                                                            Dining
                                                            <span class="submenu-expander">
                                                                <i class="fab fa-angle-down"></i>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="fitness.html">
                                                    <span class="link-icon"></span>
                                                    <span class="link-txt">
                                                        <span class="link-ext"></span>
                                                        <span class="txt">
                                                            Fitness
                                                            <span class="submenu-expander">
                                                                <i class="fab fa-angle-down"></i>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="membership.html">
                                                    <span class="link-icon"></span>
                                                    <span class="link-txt">
                                                        <span class="link-ext"></span>
                                                        <span class="txt">
                                                            Memberships
                                                            <span class="submenu-expander">
                                                                <i class="fab fa-angle-down"></i>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>





                                        </ul><!-- /#primary-nav  -->

                                    </div><!-- /#main-header-collapse -->

                                </div><!-- /.col -->



                            </div><!-- /.mainbar-row -->
                        </div><!-- /.mainbar -->
                    </div><!-- /.mainbar-container -->
                </div><!-- /.mainbar-wrap -->

            </header><!-- /.main-header -->

            <main id="content" class="content">

                <section
                    class="vc_row lqd-css-sticky bg-cover bg-center fullheight d-flex align-items-center py-5"
                    data-parallax="true"
                    data-parallax-options='{"parallaxBG":true}'
                    data-slideshow-bg="true"
                    data-slideshow-options='{"delay":2500,"imageArray":["http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/demo/preview/slide1_index.jpg","http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/demo/preview/slide2_index.jpg","http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/demo/preview/slide3_index.jpg"]}'>

                    <span class="row-bg-loader"></span>

                    <div class="liquid-row-overlay bg-black opacity-03"></div>

                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="lqd-space" style="height: 180px;"></div>

                            <div
                                class="lqd-column col-md-12 text-center px-lg-12" 
                                data-custom-animations="true"
                                data-ca-options='{"triggerHandler":"inview", "animationTarget":"all-childs", "duration":1600, "delay":250, "easing":"easeOutQuint", "direction":"forward", "initValues":{"opacity":0, "translateY":800 }, "animations":{"opacity":1, "translateY":-97}}'
                                data-parallax="true"
                                data-parallax-from='{"translateY":1}'
                                data-parallax-to='{"translateY":-150}'
                                data-parallax-options='{"easing":"linear","reverse":true,"triggerHook":"onEnter", "overflowHidden": false}'>


                                <h2
                                    class="mt-70 mb-70 text-white lh-115" style="margin-bottom: 200px;"
                                    data-fittext="true"
                                    data-fittext-options='{"compressor":0.75,"maxFontSize":"64","minFontSize":"48"}'
                                    data-split-text="true"
                                    data-split-options='{"type":"lines"}'>
                                    Sunplay Club Bangsaray  </h2>
                                <!-- <br> excutive summary</h2>
                            <a
                                href="#"
                                class="btn btn-solid text-uppercase btn-lg border-thin btn-white py-1 px-2"
                                data-localscroll="true"
                                data-localscroll-options='{"scrollBelowSection":true}'>
                                <span>
                                    <span class="btn-txt">TEXT</span>
                                </span>
                            </a>

                            <div class="lqd-space" style="height: 120px;"></div>

                            <p
                                class="text-uppercase text-white font-size-12 ltr-sp-3"
                                data-split-text="true"
                                data-split-options='{"type":"lines"}'>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br>
                                <a class="text-white" href="#">find us at</a>
                            </p>

                        </div><!-- /.lqd-column col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 -->

                            </div><!-- /.row -->
                             </section>

            </footer><!-- /.main-footer -->

        </div><!-- /#wrap -->



       
       

       <script src="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/vendors/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/js/theme-vendors.js"></script>
        <script src="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/js/theme.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/js/liquidAjaxMailchimp.min.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
               
 Run code snippet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below CSS you need to add after your custom code

```
@media(min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  header.main-header .mainbar-container .mainbar .mainbar-row {
    width: 100%;
  }
  header.main-header .mainbar-container .mainbar .col-auto {
    padding: 0px !important;
  }
}
```

add `width: 100%` in `header.main-header .mainbar-container .mainbar .mainbar-row` and add `padding: 0px !important;` in  `header.main-header .mainbar-container .mainbar .col-auto`

**NOTE:** `!important` is not recommended but in your case in `theme.min.css` at here `.main-header .mainbar-row > [class^=col]` there is a `padding-left: 15px !important` and `padding-right: 15px !important` mentioned. so needs to override it. that's why i put `padding: 0 !important`;

Hope this will help you.

```css
/* custom css for sunplay */

header.main-header .mainbar-container .mainbar {
  display: flex;
}

header.main-header .mainbar-container .mainbar .mainbar-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center !important;
  margin: 0;
}

header.main-header .mainbar-container .mainbar .col-auto {
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

header.main-header .mainbar-container .mainbar .col-auto .navbar-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.lqd-css-sticky-wrap .ld-parallax-wrap.parallax-applied span.split-inner,
.ld-parallax-wrap.parallax-applied span.split-inner {
  transform: translateY(0px) !important;
}

@media(max-width: 480px) {
  .ld-parallax-wrap .lqd-lines.split-unit .split-inner {
    font-size: 53px !important;
    letter-spacing: 0;
  }
}

@media(min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  header.main-header .mainbar-container .mainbar .mainbar-row {
    width: 100%;
  }
  header.main-header .mainbar-container .mainbar .col-auto {
    padding: 0px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/yza0jhh.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/vendors/liquid-icon/liquid-icon.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/vendors/font-awesome/css/fontawesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/vendors/font-awesome/css/brands.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/vendors/font-awesome/css/solid.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/css/theme-vendors.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/css/theme.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/css/themes/restaurant.css" />

<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
<!-- Head Libs -->

<body data-mobile-nav-trigger-alignment="right" data-mobile-nav-align="left" data-mobile-nav-style="classic" data-mobile-nav-shceme="gray" data-mobile-header-scheme="gray" data-mobile-nav-breakpoint="1199">

  <div id="wrap">

    <header class="main-header main-header-overlay">

      <div class="mainbar-wrap">
        <div class="megamenu-hover-bg"></div>
        <!-- /.megamenu-hover-bg -->
        <div class="container mainbar-container">
          <div class="mainbar">
            <div class="row mainbar-row align-items-lg-stretch">



              <div class="col-auto">

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-header-collapse">

                  <ul id="primary-nav" class="main-nav nav main-nav-hover-fade-inactive align-items-lg-stretch justify-content-lg-start" data-submenu-options='{ "toggleType":"fade", "handler":"mouse-in-out" }'>

                    <li>
                      <a href="index.html">
                        <span class="link-icon"></span>
                        <span class="link-txt">
                                                        <span class="link-ext"></span>
                        <span class="txt">
                                                            Home
                                                            <span class="submenu-expander">
                                                                <i class="fab fa-angle-down"></i>
                                                            </span>
                        </span>
                        </span>
                      </a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                      <a href="about.html">
                        <span class="link-icon"></span>
                        <span class="link-txt">
                                                        <span class="link-ext"></span>
                        <span class="txt">
                                                            About Us
                                                            <span class="submenu-expander">
                                                                <i class="fab fa-angle-down"></i>
                                                            </span>
                        </span>
                        </span>
                      </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="menu-item-has-children">
                      <a href="#">
                        <span class="link-icon"></span>
                        <span class="link-txt">
                                                        <span class="link-ext"></span>
                        <span class="txt">
                                                            Services
                                                            <span class="submenu-expander">
                                                                <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                                                            </span>
                        </span>
                        </span>
                      </a>
                      <ul class="nav-item-children">
                        <li>
                          <a href="property.html">
                            <span class="link-icon"></span>
                            <span class="link-txt">
                                                                <span class="link-ext"></span>
                            <span class="txt">
                                                                    Property Management
                                                                    <span class="submenu-expander">
                                                                        <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                                                                    </span>
                            </span>
                            </span>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="leasing.html">
                            <span class="link-icon"></span>
                            <span class="link-txt">
                                                                <span class="link-ext"></span>
                            <span class="txt">
                                                                    Leasing
                                                                    <span class="submenu-expander">
                                                                        <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                                                                    </span>
                            </span>
                            </span>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="leasing2.html">
                            <span class="link-icon"></span>
                            <span class="link-txt">
                                                                <span class="link-ext"></span>
                            <span class="txt">
                                                                    Resale
                                                                    <span class="submenu-expander">
                                                                        <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                                                                    </span>
                            </span>
                            </span>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="concierge.html">
                            <span class="link-icon"></span>
                            <span class="link-txt">
                                                                <span class="link-ext"></span>
                            <span class="txt">
                                                                    Concierge
                                                                    <span class="submenu-expander">
                                                                        <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                                                                    </span>
                            </span>
                            </span>
                          </a>
                        </li>


                      </ul>
                    </li>




                  </ul>
                  <!-- /#primary-nav  -->

                </div>
                <!-- /#main-header-collapse -->

                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" rel="home">
                    <span class="navbar-brand-inner">
                                                <img class="mobile-logo-default" src="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/demo/preview/Sunplay_Homepage_Menu_03.png" srcset="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/demo/preview/Sunplay_Homepage_Menu_03.png 1x" alt="Ave HTML Template">
                                                <img class="logo-default" src="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/demo/preview/Sunplay_Homepage_Menu_03.png" srcset="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/demo/preview/Sunplay_Homepage_Menu_03.png 1x" alt="Ave HTML Template">
                                            </span>
                  </a>
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed nav-trigger style-mobile" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-header-collapse" aria-expanded="false" data-changeclassnames='{ "html": "mobile-nav-activated overflow-hidden" }'>
                                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                            <span class="bars">
                                                <span class="bar"></span>
                                                <span class="bar"></span>
                                                <span class="bar"></span>
                                            </span>
                                        </button>
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-header -->

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-header-collapse">

                  <ul id="primary-nav" class="main-nav nav main-nav-hover-fade-inactive align-items-lg-stretch justify-content-lg-start" data-submenu-options='{ "toggleType":"fade", "handler":"mouse-in-out" }'>

                    <li>
                      <a href="restaurant.html">
                        <span class="link-icon"></span>
                        <span class="link-txt">
                                                        <span class="link-ext"></span>
                        <span class="txt">
                                                            Dining
                                                            <span class="submenu-expander">
                                                                <i class="fab fa-angle-down"></i>
                                                            </span>
                        </span>
                        </span>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="fitness.html">
                        <span class="link-icon"></span>
                        <span class="link-txt">
                                                        <span class="link-ext"></span>
                        <span class="txt">
                                                            Fitness
                                                            <span class="submenu-expander">
                                                                <i class="fab fa-angle-down"></i>
                                                            </span>
                        </span>
                        </span>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="membership.html">
                        <span class="link-icon"></span>
                        <span class="link-txt">
                                                        <span class="link-ext"></span>
                        <span class="txt">
                                                            Memberships
                                                            <span class="submenu-expander">
                                                                <i class="fab fa-angle-down"></i>
                                                            </span>
                        </span>
                        </span>
                      </a>
                    </li>





                  </ul>
                  <!-- /#primary-nav  -->

                </div>
                <!-- /#main-header-collapse -->

              </div>
              <!-- /.col -->



            </div>
            <!-- /.mainbar-row -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.mainbar -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.mainbar-container -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.mainbar-wrap -->

    </header>
    <!-- /.main-header -->

    <main id="content" class="content">

      <section class="vc_row lqd-css-sticky bg-cover bg-center fullheight d-flex align-items-center py-5" data-parallax="true" data-parallax-options='{"parallaxBG":true}' data-slideshow-bg="true" data-slideshow-options='{"delay":2500,"imageArray":["http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/demo/preview/slide1_index.jpg","http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/demo/preview/slide2_index.jpg","http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/demo/preview/slide3_index.jpg"]}'>

        <span class="row-bg-loader"></span>

        <div class="liquid-row-overlay bg-black opacity-03"></div>

        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">

            <div class="lqd-space" style="height: 180px;"></div>

            <div class="lqd-column col-md-12 text-center px-lg-12" data-custom-animations="true" data-ca-options='{"triggerHandler":"inview", "animationTarget":"all-childs", "duration":1600, "delay":250, "easing":"easeOutQuint", "direction":"forward", "initValues":{"opacity":0, "translateY":800 }, "animations":{"opacity":1, "translateY":-97}}'
              data-parallax="true" data-parallax-from='{"translateY":1}' data-parallax-to='{"translateY":-150}' data-parallax-options='{"easing":"linear","reverse":true,"triggerHook":"onEnter", "overflowHidden": false}'>


              <h2 class="mt-70 mb-70 text-white lh-115" style="margin-bottom: 200px;" data-fittext="true" data-fittext-options='{"compressor":0.75,"maxFontSize":"64","minFontSize":"48"}' data-split-text="true" data-split-options='{"type":"lines"}'>
                Sunplay Club Bangsaray </h2>
              <!-- <br> excutive summary</h2>
                            <a
                                href="#"
                                class="btn btn-solid text-uppercase btn-lg border-thin btn-white py-1 px-2"
                                data-localscroll="true"
                                data-localscroll-options='{"scrollBelowSection":true}'>
                                <span>
                                    <span class="btn-txt">TEXT</span>
                                </span>
                            </a>

                            <div class="lqd-space" style="height: 120px;"></div>

                            <p
                                class="text-uppercase text-white font-size-12 ltr-sp-3"
                                data-split-text="true"
                                data-split-options='{"type":"lines"}'>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br>
                                <a class="text-white" href="#">find us at</a>
                            </p>

                        </div><!-- /.lqd-column col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 -->

            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
      </section>

      </footer>
      <!-- /.main-footer -->

      </div>
      <!-- /#wrap -->






      <script src="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/vendors/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/js/theme-vendors.js"></script>
      <script src="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/js/theme.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://www.checkoutchiangmai.com/sunplay/demo/assets/js/liquidAjaxMailchimp.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It fixes my problem for mobile, but now when I view the desktop in Internet Explorer the logo is out of alignment with the centre: Edit added screenprint. https://imgur.com/a/LBZ3bZQ

Comment: @P.Sav before my solution, it was working properly in internet explorer?

Comment: Yes- the custom.css was added to centre the logo, before the custom.css it was not.

Comment: @P.Sav check now my answer i edited it. hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

try this one

you should remove the padding on this selector:

```html
.page .page-wrap .content-wrapper{
padding-top: 0;
}
```

or

```html
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  div.page-wrap{
    padding: 0px;
  }
}
```